# raise ValueError('Series lengths must match to compare') while manipulating dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a python beginner, and was writing code to manipulate a dataframe to aggregate rows that lie between two values. The value is extracted from one of the values in the dataframe itself.

```
a = df_gb1.loc[0,['TimeStamp']]
```

And i'm using a and a+0.4 as the two bounds to get all the rows.

```
df_gb1[df_gb1['TimeStamp'].between(a-0,a+0.4, inclusive=True)]
```

I don't know a better way to implement this, but it still gives me this error:

[image: error]

Like I said before, I'm very new to python, so I don't quite know how datatypes work with one another. It seems as if `a` is Series as well.

How do I implement what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you add sample of data with desired output?

Comment: But it seems first need remove `[]` for return scalar `a = df_gb1.loc[0,'TimeStamp']` and then `a` is `datetime` or `numeric`? If datetime, why add `+0.4` ?

Comment: @jezrael So, `'TimeStamp'` is just a float64 column. It's not actually of some special type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need remove `[]` only for return scalar `a`, else output is `Series`:

```
df_gb1 = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp':[3,3.1,5,7.1,3.4],
                   'a':[4,5,6,7,8]})

print (df_gb1)
   TimeStamp  a
0        3.0  4
1        3.1  5
2        5.0  6
3        7.1  7
4        3.4  8

a = df_gb1.loc[0,'TimeStamp']
print (a)
3.0

print (df_gb1[df_gb1['TimeStamp'].between(a-0,a+0.4, inclusive=True)])
   TimeStamp  a
0        3.0  4
1        3.1  5
4        3.4  8
```

---

```
print (df_gb1.loc[0,['TimeStamp']])
TimeStamp    3.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Comment: It worked! I'm trying to understand in what way `[]` changed the type of data returned?

Comment: It is same as `a = df_gb1[['TimeStamp']].loc[0]` - first select one column of DataFrame by subset and return `Dataframe` with one column `df_gb1[['TimeStamp']]` and then select first value - get `Series`.

Comment: also if need select first row use `a = df_gb1[['TimeStamp', 'a']].loc[0]` but if need scalar use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) - `loc['index_value', 'column_name']`

Comment: I got stuck again. I think you'll have an idea, but I'm getting the first value of `'TimeStamp'` as `a`, and then getting all rows up to `a+0.4`. Now I'm trying to access the value of `'TimeStamp'` at the row right after the last one I got in the previous statement.
`df_gb1.loc[a.tail(1).index + 1, 'TimeStamp']`, but I'm getting a Series type value now!

Comment: Nevermind, I used `nextIndex = a.index[a.index.size - 1] + 1`