# How to concatenate multiple shifted rows of a dataframe side by side?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am working on data preprocessing, where I want to arrange the samples in the dataframe in a similar fashion to an n-gram. If my samples, example, are:

```
1,2,3,4    1
0,4,2,1    1
0,2,3,5    1
1,5,5,5    0
6,5,2,1    0
```

I want the new dataframe to look like this:

```
1,2,3,4,0,4,2,1,0,2,3,5    1
0,4,2,1,0,2,3,5,1,5,5,5    0
0,2,3,5,1,5,5,5,6,5,2,1    0
```

The target variable is basically the target value of the last appended sample (i.e. third).

I am using pandas dataframe in python 3 with scikit-learn for machine learning.

How do I iterate over the dataframe samples and concatenate them side by side? I tried `concat`, but each row becomes type `Series`, and hence doesn't concatenate.

For further reference, I asked a question earlier on the same work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026974/raise-valueerrorseries-lengths-must-match-to-compare-while-manipulating-data/41027237#41027237).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Should i use only pandas ? If not, i've made a solution using lists and groupby. If you want i can share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you are trying to concatenate successively shifted versions of your data frame. One way you could this is as a list comprehension:

```
 window_size=3
 pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0:4].shift(-i) for i in range(window_size)] 
           + [df.iloc[:,4].shift(1 - window_size)], axis=1).iloc[0:1 - window_size]

       a  b  c  d      a    b    c    d      a    b    c    d    y
0      1  2  3  4    0.0  4.0  2.0  1.0    0.0  2.0  3.0  5.0  1.0
1      0  4  2  1    0.0  2.0  3.0  5.0    1.0  5.0  5.0  5.0  0.0
2      0  2  3  5    1.0  5.0  5.0  5.0    6.0  5.0  2.0  1.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

That's more of a numpy question

Code for generating the data

```
data =np.array([[1,2,3,4],
[0,4,2,1  ],
[0,2,3,5  ],
[1,5,5,5  ],
[6,5,2,1  ]])
labels = np.array([[1,1,1,0,0]]).transpose()
```

'Reshaping' the data

```
row_ids = [range(k,k+3) for k in range(x.shape[0]-2)]
new_data = np.reshape(data[row_ids, :], [data.shape[0]-2, 12])
new_labels = labels[2:]
```

Results:

```
print new_data
print new_labels

[[1 2 3 4 0 4 2 1 0 2 3 5]
 [0 4 2 1 0 2 3 5 1 5 5 5]
 [0 2 3 5 1 5 5 5 6 5 2 1]]
[[1]
 [0]
 [0]]
```

Finally, making a pandas DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
df['new_labels'] = new_labels
```

As a side note: For getting a better understanding see how we sample the data with row_ids

```
print row_ids

[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```